# AdMob Open app ad showing even after resuming the app

Tags: admob

I implemented AdMob's open app ad and it is showing way to often - every time the app is opened, every time the app is resumed. I tried to find a way to "sleep" the ad for some period and it led to no avail. Does AdMob support this scenario? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `AppOpenAd` implementation is based on the idea of showing Ads on the app's `onResume()` state, no matter how frequently your App hits that state. If a cached Ad is available, it **will** be shown.

There are 2 ways to handle this scenario here:

1. Use **Frequency Capping** from your AdMob dashboard.
   AdMob Dashboard > App > Ad Units > Select Ad Unit > Advanced Settings > Frequency Capping.
2. You could change the behaviour via the `ProcessLifecycleOwner`'s observer.
   You can locally save the time (Eg: `SharedPreferences`) when the Ad is shown via the `onAdShowedFullScreenContent` callback & then check again later in the `onResume()` if it is suitable to show the Ad again by comparing the `(currentTime - savedTime)`.

You can also try this library that I've created that could help: https://github.com/ItzNotABug/AppOpenAdManager

Comment: Hey, Darshan!

Thanks for the proposed solutions. I implemented the first due to being easier. It worked. I never know this option even existed.